# Edge Detection in a particular frame of entire image

Tags: ios, image-processing, gpuimage

I am using `GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter` from project **GPUImage** for edge detection.

My requirement is that I want to detect edges in an image but only at centre frame of 200 x 200 and rest of the image should not be touched.

There is no direct api in framework to provide `CGRect` for edge detection coordinates. I do have an alternate approach of cropping down the original image and passing it for Edge Detection and finally super-imposing on the original one. But this sounds like a hack to me.

Any idea if there is a direct way to do it?

Comment: i think your alternate approach is the only way.

Comment: Yeah, if you get any solution do let us know, Cropping may take a little time, you can use Metal/OpenGL to make it little fast and then apply that filter

Comment: Unfortunately, It is the nature of image processing that we have the alternate approch is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do that is as you suggest, do a crop and work with the cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to switch over to the newer [GPUImage 2](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2), this is one of the core new features in that version of the framework. Filters can be partially applied to any region of an image, leaving the remainder of the image untouched. This includes the Sobel edge detection, and the masking of the image can be done using arbitrary shapes:

[image: Partial Sobel edge detection]

To partially apply a Sobel edge detection filter, you'd set up the filter chain as normal, then set a mask to the filter. In the below, the mask is a circle, generated to match a 480x640 image:

```
let circleGenerator = CircleGenerator(size:Size(width:480, height:640))
edgeDetectionFilter.mask = circleGenerator
circleGenerator.renderCircleOfRadius(0.25, center:Position.center, circleColor:Color.white, backgroundColor:Color.transparent)
```

The area within the circle will have the filter applied, and the area outside will simply passthrough the previous pixel colors.

This uses a stencil mask to perform this partial rendering, so it doesn't slow rendering by much. Unfortunately, I've pretty much ceased my work on the Objective-C version of GPUImage, so this won't be getting backported to that older version of the  framework.

Comment: Hi Brad. Thank you so much for your response. My project is completely developed in Objective-C. Is there any way I can get this working on Objective-C? Or can I use the Swift based project in my Obj-C project?

Comment: @EvolGate - Unfortunately, the new version of the framework was intended entirely for use with Swift projects. Interoperability with Objective-C was not something I designed for, and I'm not sure if it's achievable with the interfaces and data types I use. I haven't tried, though.

Comment: Hi Brad, is it possible to use GPUImage 2 to convert background of an image to transparent?

Comment: @userx - Yes, via chroma keying. There are multiple examples of this in the sample applications.

Comment: Awesome thanks, my use case is to mostly get out white background from the background. I will check out the sample apps. Thanks for you work on this.